# Подняться или выйти из метро

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильно сказать, выйти из метро или подняться из метро?
Подняться с колен или встать с колен
Выйти из подвала или подняться из подвала.

Answer (score 1):

Да не надо ниоткуда подниматься - никто же не просит пошагового рецепта (отчета).

С подвалом и коленями синонимичные конструкции, хоть поднимайся, хоть вставай,

а из метро - выходим, если это не отрывок из сочинения "Как я знакомился с метрополитеном".